# Error was not caught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'electron' in undefined at next-dev.js:8

Tags: webpack, electron, next.js

I'm facing this error while trying to run next.js in dev mode. I have no idea why this is  happening thought I am not even using electron in this application.

`Error was not caught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'electron' in undefined at next-dev.js:8`

[image: webpack:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js:formatted]

This is my next.config

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@my-storybook'])
const watchStorybook = require('@my-storybook/watch-storybook');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ENV = require('./config/environments/environment')

let GPA_ENV;

switch (process.env.API_URL_BASE) {
  case 'https://my-api':
    GPA_ENV = 'k15'
    break;
  case 'https://my-api2':
    GPA_ENV = 'development'
    break;
  default:
    GPA_ENV = 'homolog'
}

module.exports = withTM({
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    if(dev) watchStorybook();

    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        process: {
          env: {
            GPA_ENV : JSON.stringify(GPA_ENV)
          }
        }
      })
    )

    return config
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL_BASE: process.env.API_URL_BASE || ENV.URLS.API_URL_BASE || 'https://my-api3',
    IMAGE_URL_BASE: process.env.IMAGE_URL_BASE || ENV.URLS.IMAGE_URL_BASE || 'https://my-api',
    STOMP_URL_BASE: process.env.STOMP_URL_BASE || 'https://my-websocket',
    STOMP_RECONNECT_DELAY: process.env.STOMP_RECONNECT_DELAY || '10000',
    SECURE_COOKIES: process.env.SECURE_COOKIES || '0',
    ROBOTS_NOINDEX: process.env.ROBOTS_NOINDEX || '0',
    SITE_URL_BASE: process.env.SITE_URL_BASE || 'https://my-api',
    GPA_ENV: GPA_ENV,
    USE_INTELIPOST: !!Number(process.env.USE_INTELIPOST),
  },
})
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "create-component": "node config/scripts/create-component",
    "create-page": "node config/scripts/create-page",
    "pa:dev": "npm run env:pa:dev && npm run dev",
    "pa:hlg": "npm run env:pa:hlg && npm run dev",
    "adega:dev": "npm run env:adega:dev && npm run dev",
    "adega:hlg": "npm run env:adega:hlg && npm run dev",
    "adega:stage": "npm run env:adega:stage && npm run dev",
    "ex:dev": "npm run env:ex:dev && npm run dev",
    "ex:hlg": "npm run env:ex:hlg && npm run dev",
    "env:pa:dev": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/pa target=dev output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:adega:dev": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/adega target=dev output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:ex:dev": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/ex target=dev output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:pa:hlg": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/pa target=hlg output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:adega:hlg": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/adega target=hlg output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:ex:hlg": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/ex target=hlg output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:pa:prd": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/pa target=prd output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:adega:prod": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/adega target=prd output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:adega:stage": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/adega target=prd output=./config/environments/environment.js",
    "env:ex:prd": "node ./node_modules/app-json-env-gen/cli.js dir=./__env__/ex target=prd output=./config/environments/environment.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-storybook": "1.0.1-7",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.13",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.13",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "next": "9.3.6",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^3.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "app-json-env-gen": "^0.6.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "5.11.2",
    "tslint-react": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I've tryed:
to remove node_modules and package-lock, with no success.
Search for `electron` in my app, but there is not such word, only in next.js  node_modules files.

I don't know what more I should do.

Can anyone give some light on this?? Thanks people, you are awesome!

Comment: may be its not related to your package.json or config file. its related to something you are doing, may be search, map or filtering somewhere ?

Comment: For me this error started happening after upgrading `dotenv-webpack` from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0. I've logged the issue with that plugin: https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/issues/238

Comment: @EvHaus, God bless you. you deserve a medal

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to understand why it happens but it can be fixed by simply adding

```
if (typeof process.versions === 'undefined') process.versions = {};
```

to your `/pages/_app.js` file.